# Put methods in actual class or as static in separate class

Tags: java

Is it better to have methods in the actual class or to have them in an Util class as static?
example:

```
String name = user.getName();
```

or

```
String name = Utils.getName(user);
```

Is there a difference in performance?

Comment: it depends on your design (and your goals). performance doesnt matter a lot.

Comment: Wait, so instance methods as opposed to static methods? Don't worry about performance, static will be more readable, especially if aren't you the properties of the instance variable in the first place.

Comment: From a design point of  view, seems like `getName()` (if speaking of a user's name) should be in the `User` class.

Comment: Is `name` an intrinsic property of `User`? If yes, put it in the `User` class; if no, put it in a utility class.

Comment: Depends on your design. Utils class should be reusable and should perform operations based on the input and output.

Comment: The second might be useful if you want to use a particular string in place of the name when your user is `null`, and you don't want to keep explicitly null-checking it everywhere. Otherwise, the first is more compliant with OO style.

Comment: Why the hell are my questions always downvoted :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is better to put the methods where they logically belong.  If a user has a name that can be accessed, then in the `User` class define the `getName()` method.  It is simple and organized and facilitates maintenance of your code.

Comment: Also `Utils.getName(user)` implies `user.name` is not private. Which kills encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to access things in a static way, and you don't need anything to do with a particular instance of a class, then keep a static.

It will be more readable, you'll save memory (no `new` keyword!), and it will be easier to manage.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two reasons to prefer putting the methods in the relevant class:

- Grouping strongly related code together makes reading easier.
- Using the minimum scope reduces the risk of a method developing several uses that are only coincidentally related. That can inhibit refactoring.

Neither of those reasons apply to genuine utility methods, such as `Math.sin`.

Answer (score 0):

One more consideration is that if you have the static method approach like `Utils.getName(user)` you should have either

- a non-private `user.name` or
- a public getter on `user.name`

First kills encapsulation, and second creates redundancy in cases where `Utils.getName(user)`  is just a simple get.

Answer (score 0):

`User.getName(user)` preserves encapsulation but allows for the advantages of a static function.  All of these options are likely to be as performant as you need.